# Problem with Copy pasting text from a document on ubuntu

Tags: files, libreoffice, text-processing, copy-and-paste

Version: 19.10

The problem is while i copy some text from a file to libre office or google docs ( where i am creating my own document ), after pasting the text takes same formatting as of the source, i am not here talking about formatted and unformatted text, i knw the use of ctrl+shift+v

The pasting output is not appending to end of original line and hence leaving some trailing spaces
I believe you wont understand thats why i am attaching a short video too please have a look and tell me if there is any solution to this. I want the structure to be like that which is shown in the end of the video after pasting the text as it was in WINDOWS 
[YOUTUBE VIDEO HERE](https://youtu.be/WQeuBER5V4M)

Answer (score 1):

Try to paste it in a no format text editor(leafpad, or what you have installed) and the paste it to google docs. It may delete the "format" that you dont want there.

Answer (score 1):

Use "Paste Special" instead of "Paste" and select "Unformatted Text" in Libre Office.

Answer (score 0):

This is just how text in PDFs works - when you copy text that spans multiple lines, you get line breaks. [Other forums](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-reader/copy-paste-from-pdf-without-the-formatting/td-p/2952176) have suggested that [this website](https://www.textfixer.com/tools/remove-line-breaks.php) might be able to help you remove those line breaks.